# Unable to display 2 intents together

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use 2 intents, but only one of them works at a time. if i remove one then the other will work but if i put them both together then only one of them works here is my code

```
    private void addReviews(String SName, String SFacility) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddReview.class);
        i.putExtra("Stations", SName);
        startActivity(i);

        Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddReview.class);
        a.putExtra("Facilities", SFacility);
        startActivity(a);

    }
```

AddReview.class

```
TextView txtestablishment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewStationReview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String Stations = i.getStringExtra("Stations");

        txtestablishment.setText("Add Review for " + Stations);

        Intent a = getIntent();
        String Ftype = a.getStringExtra("Facilities");

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); {

            String name = a.getStringExtra("Facilities");

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(name,",");
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()){
                al.add((String)tokenizer.nextElement());
            }

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, R.id.textView1,
                al);

        spFacilityType.setAdapter(aa1);

        spFacilityType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

This is the one not working

```
Intent i = getIntent();
final String Stations = i.getStringExtra("Stations");

txtestablishment.setText("Add Review for " + Stations);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your original code starts two activities**, the latter is visible, when you close it, you'll the first. My guess is **you want to start single activity with multiple meta-data** passed to it. You can pass virtually unlimited number of extras via an intent. These extras are identified by a unique key for that intent instance (here "Stations" and "Facilities").

TL;DR: What you most probably need looks like this:

```
private void addReviews(String SName, String SFacility) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AddReview.class);
    i.putExtra("Stations", SName);
    i.putExtra("Facilities", SFacility);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't start 2 activities at a time with 2 intents. (where would you put them on screen?)

Comment: so you say 2 activities without Uİ can br started at same tame with 2 startActivity()?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your are sending two different intents to the same place, just put both extras in one intent and call them from it.  Looking at your code I can't see a reason to call that same activity twice.

Just do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddReview.class);
i.putExtra("Stations", SName);
i.putExtra("Facilities", SFacility);
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: Ah sorry, mistake a should be i.  You shouldnt have a anymore.